# How to distribute QLabels in QStatusBar evenly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qstatusbar

I am trying to distribute QLabels evenly and in the same manner as columns in QTableView (column-width-wise).

Consequently, I would like to replace the strings (data.columns.values.tolist()[index]) in QLabels for "count: CountofRows" for columns that cannot be summed up and for "sum: SumofRows" for columns that can be summed up. If possible this should be updated whenever filter (QSortFilterProxyModel) is used.

I have read these posts: [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759146/how-to-auto-expand-label-width-in-qstatusbar) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45791136/pyqt5-how-to-align-the-elements-of-the-status-bar) but still have not managed to make this work.

Here is my code, at this stage it just fills QLabels in QStatusBar:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from pandas import *
import sys


class TBWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TBWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        fList = [['Ajvi', 'Ostatní textil', 'Holesovice', 1, 2],
                 ['Ajvi', 'Sukně', 'Holesovice', 2, 5],
                 ['Ajvi', 'Šaty', 'Holesovice', 2, 0],
                 ['Belusi', 'Brože', 'Fler', 0, 1],
                 ['Belusi', 'Brože', 'Holesovice', 0, 5],
                 ['PP', 'Sukně', 'E-shop', 25, 10],
                 ['PP', 'Sukně', 'Fler', 7, 6],
                 ['PP', 'Sukně', 'Holesovice', 15, 13],
                 ['PP', 'Sukně', 'Other', 6, 2],
                 ['PP', 'Sukně', 'Sashe', 6, 2],
                 ['PP', 'Tašky', 'E-shop', 2, 1],
                 ['PP', 'Tašky', 'Holesovice', 3, 1],
                 ['PP', 'Šaty', 'E-shop', 1, 0]]

        data = DataFrame(fList, columns = ['Seller', 'Section', 'Store', 'Total_pieces: 2017', 'Total_pieces: 2018'])

        self.setWindowTitle('Window')
        self.centralwidget  = QWidget(self)
        self.lineEdit       = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.view           = QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox       = QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.label          = QLabel(self.centralwidget)

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.view, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("Filter")

        self.model = PandasModel(data)
        self.proxy = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.view.setModel(self.proxy)

        for column in range(self.view.horizontalHeader().count()):
            self.view.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(column, QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.comboBox.addItems(list(data.columns.values))
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.on_lineEdit_textChanged)
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged)

##        mWdg = QWidget()
##        mWdg.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
##        for index, element in enumerate(data.columns.values):
##            mWdg.layout().addWidget(QLabel(data.columns.values.tolist()[index]))
##        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(mWdg)

        for index, element in enumerate(data.columns.values):
            self.statusBar().addWidget(QLabel(data.columns.values.tolist()[index]), index)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_lineEdit_textChanged(self, text):
        search = QRegExp(text, Qt.CaseInsensitive, QRegExp.RegExp)
        self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(search)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(self, index):
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(index)

class PandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])
        return None

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[col]
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = TBWindow()
    main.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any suggestions how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QStatusBar.addPermanentWidget(widget[, stretch=0])

Parameters: 
widget  – QWidget
stretch – QtCore.int

Adds the given widget permanently to this status bar, reparenting the widget if it isn’t already a child of this QStatusBar object. The stretch parameter is used to compute a suitable size for the given widget as the status bar grows and shrinks. The default stretch factor is 0, i.e giving the widget a minimum of space.

```
    mWdg = QWidget()
    mWdg.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
    for index, element in enumerate(data.columns.values):
        mWdg.layout().addWidget(QLabel(data.columns.values.tolist()[index]))
    self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(mWdg, 1)   # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    #for index, element in enumerate(data.columns.values):
    #    self.statusBar().addWidget(QLabel(data.columns.values.tolist()[index]), index)
```

[image]